# O que significa o atributo data-reactid?

Tags: html, react

Estava olhando em alguns sites na internet, e vi, no código fonte de algumas páginas,  um atributo chamado `data-reactid`, inserido em elementos `div`.

O que é este atributo, qual sua função e no que influencia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse `data-reactid` é uma atributo `data-` de HTML usado pelo React para interagir com o DOM. O React cria um DOM virtual, uma coleção de arrays e objetos que manipula internamente para evitar mudar o DOM caso não seja necessário.

Uma vez que a maior parte de interação com uma aplicação são trocas de valores e ações que não precisa estar no DOM, o react deixa "uma porta", um ponteiro, para cada elemento através desse `data-reactid`. Assim, quando for altura de mudar algo no DOM, o elemento tem um atributo para ser referenciado.

Não sei bem se isso é util em debug, se o React guarda esse `data-reactid` para o procurar no DOM ou se ele é só para espelhar o que se passa internamente. Imagino que para debug e mostrar o que se passa internamente, e o DOM virtual têm referências ao objeto/elemento em questão.

Comment: Seria excelente o [@fabio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/17791/fabiomcosta) dar uma olhada aqui e deixar uma resposta também...

Answer (score 0):

Ele pertence ao Framework [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) e é adicionado de modo automático pelo próprio Framework, para identificar algum componente, a fim de efetuar alguma atualização e/ou manipulação de conteúdo.

Este método, porém, era utilizado em versões anteriores. A partir da versão 15, segundo a própria [documentação do React](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/03/07/react-v15-rc1.html#document.createelement-is-in-and-data-reactid-is-out), esse atributo não é mais utilizado, ao invés do `data-reactid` você pode notar alguns outros atributos, como `data-reactroot` ou até mesmo comentários, como `<!-- /react-text: 2 -->`.